# Issue matching partially underlined string

Tags: python, regex

I have a database of words to search and replace. See row 16 id:17

[image]

I want to match string "6 (six) months" in a docx document using python regex. However, if the string is partially underlined, the string does not get replaced into the desired "y months".

For example:
[image]

main.py calls regex dfinition from docx.py

```
for x in mycol.find():
            docx_replace_regex(document, re.compile(x["original"]+'\S*', re.IGNORECASE), x["replace"])
```

docx.py

def docx_replace_regex(doc_obj, regex , replace):

```
for p in doc_obj.paragraphs:

    if regex.search(p.text):
        # print(p.text)
        inline = p.runs
        # Loop added to work with runs (strings with same style)
        for i in range(len(inline)):
            # print(i)
            if regex.search(inline[i].text):
                # myTexts.append(inline[i].text)
                text = regex.sub(replace, inline[i].text)
                inline[i].text = text
                # print(text)
```

My code works for every word in the database as long as its not partially underlined.

Comment: post you code & read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi will this do?

Comment: please let me know how i can improve my question

Comment: I would like to see the result of calling repr on that example. It might show how the underline is encoded.

Comment: whats repr @DanD.

Comment: It is very useful to use the repr function to produce an ASCII only representation of a string when printing it doesn't show what is going on. [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) Return a string containing a printable representation of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are matching `\([a-z]+\)` but apparently, underlined characters in your database are stored as different characters from `[a-z]`.

It's likely text in your database is stored as UTF-8 and underlining might then just be 'underline characters', which you could filter out before applying the regex (or you could include the underline character in the regex, if supported).

To remove underlining UTF-8 characters (assuming this is how it's done in your database, we have no access and you have provided no sample):

```
import re

line = 't͟e͟x͟t͟͟'.encode("utf-8")
underline = b'\xcd\x9f'

print(re.sub(underline, b'', line))


line = 't͟e͟x͟t͟͟'
underline = b'\xcd\x9f'.decode('utf-8')

print(re.sub(underline, '', line))
```

Comment: thank you for your response. " you could filter out before applying the regex" how would i go about this

Comment: the sample for the database is above

Comment: A picture of what you see on your screen is not the same as a data sample.